# Grouping hash within an array

Tags: ruby

I'm currently finding it difficult to get my head around grouping hashes within an array. I've played around with the group_by method but haven't gotten anywhere.

```
students = [
    {name: "James", cohort: :December},
    {name: "David", cohort: :April},
    {name: "Kyle", cohort: :December}  
]
```

What would be the simplest way to group the students by cohort ... e.g. It would print this

```
December = James, Kyle
April = David
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use group_by method like show below

```
students = [
  {name: "James", cohort: :December},
  {name: "David", cohort: :April},
  {name: "Kyle", cohort: :December}
]

grouped_students = students.group_by { |student| student[:cohort] }

grouped_students.each do |cohort, students|
  puts "#{cohort} = #{students.map { |student| student[:name] }.join(', ')}"
end
```

Here is another way using `each_with_object` method.

```
students_by_cohort = students.each_with_object({}) do |student, result|
  cohort = student[:cohort]
  result[cohort] ||= []
  result[cohort] << student[:name]
end

students_by_cohort.each do |cohort, students|
  puts "#{cohort}: #{students.join(", ")}"
end
```

Output

```
December = James, Kyle
April = David
```

Comment: Use `each` to iterate, `map` only if you're transforming. Here you use `map { ... puts }`.

Comment: While the `each_with_object` approach isn't as elegant here, sometimes it has its advantages, but it's worth using `each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [ ] }` to create a default empty array type hash. This makes the inner part super simple: `r[c] << s[:name]`.